# How to autopopulate a dropdown with jquery in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this controller function:

```
public function showclientsinvoice($id)
{
    $clients = Clients::find($id);

    return response()->json($clients);
}
```

That makes me autopopulate the input fields with clients data.

My problem is I don't know how to autopopulate a dropdown list

My jquery script is this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $('body').on('click', '#show-client', function () {
          var userURL = $(this).data('url');
          $.get(userURL, function (data) {
              $('#invoicemodal').modal('show');
              $('#client-id').val(data.id);
              $('#client-name').val(data.nume);
              $('#client-ctara').val(data.tara);
              $('#cif').val(data.cif);
              $('#cif1').val(data.cif1);
              $('#rgc').val(data.rgc);
              $('#rgc1').val(data.rgc1);
              $('#rgc2').val(data.rgc2);
              $('#rgc3').val(data.rgc3);
              $('#cp').val(data.cp);
              $('#judet').val(data.judet);
            
            
          })
         
       });
        
    });
   
</script>
```

How can I integrate in this script an autopopulate for dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery in this way to add dynamically dropdown options:

```
let options = {
    a : 'one',
    b : 'two'
};
var select = $('#idselect');
$.each(options, function(val, text) {
    select.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

Comment: And can I switch a: 'one' and b:'two' with    $('#iban1').val(data.iban1); for example?

Comment: Yes sure, with any values you need. you can even ommit the val if the text is enough.